# WP_Query to display number of custom post type filtered (order by) taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to display the number of posts made in custom post type "incidents" by the custom taxonomy "store".

eg.

Store 1: 8 posts

Store 2: 6 posts

etc.

I have been looking through here and only been able to find how to display the actual posts, which I do not need. 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try running a custom query for each:

```
$args_1 = array(
    'post_type' => 'incidents',
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'store',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'store_1',
        ),
    ),
);
$count_1 = count( get_posts( $args_1 ) );

echo 'Store 1: ' . $count_1 . ' posts';
```